# How to tell what bookmark is loaded...so that I can rename the bookmark?

Tags: safari, safari-extensions

As a Safari/Mac user...How can I tell what bookmark is loaded in the browser...So that I can rename the bookmark?

Similar to what Chrome offers?

Comment: Not everybody uses Chrome, so can you explain what exactly Chrome offers and why simply right-clicking a bookmark isn‘t the solution you are looking for?

Answer (score 2):

Press `Command` + `Shift` + `L` and it will show a menu on the left side of Safari that allows you to view bookmarks. Click on **Bookmarks**. Scroll down on the side menu, a search bar will appear on top. Enter in a keyword/website name and the bookmark will pop up. Right-click on the bookmark to rename it.

Comment: How does that tell you which bookmark the current page is - which is what I think the question is about, but I don't use Chrome so I might be wrong

Comment: @mmmmmm I edited my answer to include more info.